# Python libraries in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed eclipse and python to program my project. I noticed that when I import some libraries as "from scipy import stats", I received an error stating "unresolved import stats".

However, when I checked the built in libraries that exists on /usr/lib/python2.7, I found scipy folder in that directory.

Do I need to add EACH FOLDER for the library, or just the parent folder will include the subfolders as well?

Thanks,

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which Eclipse are you running?

Comment: I love eclipse, but JetBrains just release pycharm community as a freely available download, and it hands down stomps eclipse for python development IMHO.  http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ - great integration and plugin support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Eclipse's `Preferences` and find `PyDev` you should see a list of libraries. If you're not noticing your library there you can add it manually. I myself haven't ever had a problem with newly installed packages so it's possible you didn't set it up/install the packages correctly.

```
Preferences -> PyDev -> (Find your library/package)
```